# Limit of a particular series

Tags: sequences-and-series

Consider the series $a_n=1+\frac{2}{3}+\frac{4}{9}+...+\frac{2^n}{3^n}$.  I need to find an upper bound (a value that is bigger than the series for every natural number n). I found that $a_n<n+1$. Is that enough or there is an exact value that is bigger than the series?

Comment: Hint: Geometric series.

Comment: Try $$a_n<3{}$$

Comment: $a_n < \frac{2}{3} a_n + 1$.

Comment: What is asked is a *constant* upper bound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $n\in \Bbb N,$

$$a_n=\sum_{i=0}^n(\frac{2}{3})^i=\frac {1-(\frac {2}{3})^{n+1}}{1-\frac {2}{3}} $$

$$< \frac {1}{\frac {1}{3}} $$

$$\implies a_n <3.$$

Answer (score 2):

I claim that $a_n \leq 3$. Notice $a_{n + 1} = 1 + \frac{2}{3} a_n$. So we can prove inductively that if $a_n \leq 3$, then
\begin{align*}
a_{n + 1} & = 1 + \frac{2}{3} a_n \\
& \leq 1 + \frac{2}{3} (3) \\
& = 3 .
\end{align*}
And voila, you have *an* upper bound. But we can show it's the optimal upper bound by observing that the sequence is increasing and bounded, and thus has a limit $L$. You can also see
$$ L = 1 + \frac{2}{3} L \Rightarrow L = 3 .$$
So $3$ is the least upper bound to the sequence.